# MongoDB covered query on embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I am learning indexing in MongoDB

My sample schema is:

1. name
2. location

   - street
   - number

I have created two indexes, on `name` and on `location.number`.
When I type

```
db.table.find({ 'name': 'Steve' }, { _id: 0, 'name': 1 }).explain('executionStats')
```

I got covered query, but when I type

```
db.table.find({ 'location.number': 46 }, { _id: 0, 'location.number': 1 }).explain('executionStats')
```

the `totalDocsExamined` is not equal to 0 so it is not covered query. Why? The query contains only one field, which index has and `_id` is excluded same as in first query. Covered queries are not working with embedded documents?

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not. It is [very well documented restriction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#restrictions-on-indexed-fields):

> An index cannot cover a query if any of the indexed fields in the query predicate or returned in the projection are fields in embedded documents.

Comment: As of MongoDB 3.6 a sub-document field can be included in a covered index.  `Changed in version 3.6: An index can cover a query on fields within embedded documents. `

Answer (score 1):

The quoted text on [Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418984/3211335) answer no longer appears in the linked site. I still don't do my own research with the data I managed with this, but I think this may be possible now.

According to the new docs:

> Changed in version 3.6: An index can cover a query on fields within
>   embedded documents.

Version 3.6 was [released](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-mongodb-36) in November 2017, so definitely a new feature for the date the OP was made.

See [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#index-embedded-document-fields) for more examples.